# nodejs: Prisma: Upsert failing for model. Prisma is assuming that relationship name is the column name when upserting

Tags: node.js, prisma

Prisma: 5.2.0

nodejs: 18.17.1

```
Table A {
 a_id   String @id @db.VarChar(100)
 a_name String @db.VarChar(100)
}

 Table B {
  b_id    String @id @db.VarChar(100)
  b_name  String @db.VarChar(100)
  b_a_id  String @db.VarChar(100)
  A       A?     @relation(fields: [a_a_id], references: [a_id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "A_fk")
  
}
```

a_id is referenced in table B here. When I try to upsert, Prisma is throwing the error

`Unknown argument a_id. Did you mean 'A' which is the relationship name. Available options are marked with ?.`

I am unsure why Prisma is taking the relationship name instead of the actual column name.

```
prisma[B].upsert({
 'b_a_id': '123',
 'b_id': 'b_id_1'
})
```